# Inconsistent showing of example citations in reputation page and achievements tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation

First, the same change (from an example citation) listed twice in my Reputation history:
[image: My rep page]
What's odd is that the first time it's listed, it doesn't seem to count towards the total number of events and total reputation for the Creating and Initializing Arrays block. It's just sort of… there.

The second oddity is something (worth 10 rep—2 citations?) showing up in my inbox, but not in my rep history:

[image: A different part of my rep page]
So what exactly happened there?

[image: :eyebrow:] what is going on here?

UPDATE: the rep change in the second image has now reduced to 5 rep, and has appeared in my history:
[image]

Comment: For future reference, the first screenshot is looking your reputation on Oct. 28. The second screenshot is from today (Nov. 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this bug - we were improperly adding citation rep events to the per-post grouping.

A fix is rolling out now.